# Enable binary mode while restoring a Database from an SQL dump

Tags: database, mysql, database-restore

I am  extremely new to MySQL and am running it on Windows. I am trying to restore a Database from a dumpfile in MySQL, but I get the following error:

```
$ >mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D database -o < dump.sql
ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'SQLite format 3'.
```

I have tried putting `--binary-mode` in the ini file but it still gives the same error. What should I do? Please help.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Nick in his comment I tried `$ > mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D database --binary-mode -o < dump.sql` but it gave me the following `ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\☻'.` 
It is a 500 Mb dump file, and when I view its contents using gVIM, all I can see is expressions and data which is not comprehensible.

Comment: mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D database --binary-mode -o < dump.sql

Comment: That gives ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\☻'.

Comment: I was getting this error but got a fresh MySQL dump and tried re-importing and it worked fine. Our MySQL dump comes in two zipped parts that have to be concatenated and then unzipped. I think the initial unzipping was interrupted, resulting in a `.sql` file with weird characters and encodings. The second attempt worked fine.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

Unzip the file, and then import again.

Comment: Do you mean zip and then unzip?

Comment: This is how it worked for me, unzip the db.sql.gz, you will get db.sql, rename it again to db.sql.gz, don't zip it, just rename it, then unzip again to db.sql and now you will get the right file to import.

Comment: @MotsManish Seriously? I thought this was a joke. I'll give it a shot and see if that works.

Comment: This worked when I compressed a file to `.tar.bz2` using linux and used WinRAR to extract it on Windows. _I don't get it_. Nice.

Comment: face palm ‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️

Comment: Same thing just happened to me ^^'
Genious.

Comment: I feel really ashamed. But actually this was helpful. It works!

Comment: How do you unzip a db file?

Comment: @Jeff.H you can actually rename it to .zip or .gz and use winzip or any other unzip tool. You might have to experiment unzipping the content also, because for some weird reason I have the content zipped also when I exported a dump. Or on terminal you can use 'untar'

Comment: thats poor. What if there's a very large file?? should be able to import the zip

Answer (score 93):

I meet the same problem in windows restoring a dump file. My dump file was created with windows powershell and mysqldump like:

`mysqldump db > dump.sql`

The problem comes from the default encoding of powershell is UTF16. To look deeper into this, we can use "file" utility of GNU, and there exists a windows version [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm). 
The output of my dump file is:

*Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators.*

Then a conversion of coding system is needed, and there are various software can do this. For example in emacs,

`M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system`

then input required coding system such as utf-8.

**And in the future, for a better mysqldump result, use:**

`mysqldump <dbname> -r <filename>`

and then the output is handled by `mysqldump` itself but not redirection of powershell.

reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44721/error-while-restoring-a-database-from-an-sql-dump

Comment: mysqldump <dbname> -r <filename>  anyone using Windows or DOS systems this is the solution. UTF-8 file conversion is a distraction. Use the -r option, which directs the output to the filename and handles CRLF carriage return linefeed  (\r\n) that windows puts in files, this is where the problem is. Thanks for the Excellent Solution!

Comment: On a practical note, I got around this after creating the file in Powershell by converting the generated file to UTF-8 using Notepad++.

Comment: This answer, if I hadn't dug in, would have saved me hours of searching for the correct answer. Wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: I did the same as @PeterMajeed . A quick convert-and-save with NotePad++ allowed me to restore an existing file

Comment: this is the best answer for me, not sure why the accepted answer has 200+ votes compared to this one

Comment: I had the same thing and needed to script the conversion
`iconv -f UTF16// -t UTF-8// mysqldump.sql -o mysqldump.sql.utf8`

Answer (score 42):

In Windows machine, please follows the preceding steps.

1. Open file in notepad.
2. Click on Save as
3. Select Encoding type UTF-8.

Now source your db.

Comment: This worked for me for an SQL backup-file that had been created by running mysqldump via Powershell. The Poweshell output was UTF-16. Changing to UTF-8 solved the problem and allowed me to restore my detabase from the backup-file.

Comment: My file was +5GB :'(  Powershell to the rescue:      $utf8 = New-Object Text.Utf8Encoding($false); Get-Content .\index.htm | Out-File -Encoding $utf8 -FilePath .\index.utf8.htm;

Answer (score 16):

If you don't have enough space or don't want to waste time decompressing it, Try this command.

```
gunzip < compressed-sqlfile.gz | mysql -u root -p
```

Don't forget to replace compressed-sqlfile.gz with your file name.

.gz restore will not work without the command I provided above.

Comment: You should add `database_name` after the command, so it will import the sql file to that database, or it will cause error. Ex: `gunzip < compressed-sqlfile.gz | mysql -u root -p your_database_name`

Comment: The SQL file already contains the name of the database.

Answer (score 11):

Extract your file with Tar archiving tool. you can use it in this way:

```
tar xf example.sql.gz
```

Comment: This was the answer for me. At first, I gunzipped .sql.gz file whic resulted in the "binary" error when importing. Turned out the file was tar/gzipped so I had to *tar xvf* the file first then it let me import it.

Answer (score 10):

I had this error once, after running `mysqldump` on Windows PowerShell like so:

```
mysqldump -u root p my_db --no-data --no-create-db --no-create-info --routines --triggers --skip-opt --set-gtid-purged=OFF > db_objects.sql
```

What I did was change it to this (pipe instead to Set-Content):

```
mysqldump -u root p my_db --no-data --no-create-db --no-create-info --routines --triggers --skip-opt --set-gtid-purged=OFF | Set-Content db_objects.sql
```

And the problem went away!

Comment: I'm getting mysqldump: Got errno 32 on

Comment: See if this thread might be able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288271/mysqldump-got-errno-32-on-write

Comment: Thank you. The issue was that I exported the db with an old version of phpmyadmin on an old mysql server. Not sure why but half of the database was exported in clear text and the other half gzip-ed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know why I usually use Linux...

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried opening in notepad++ (or another editor) and converting/saving us to UTF-8?

See: [notepad++ converting ansi encoded file to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/notepad-converting-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8)

Another option may be to use textwrangle to open and save the file as UTF-8: http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick for me. Open the file in NotePad++.  Encoding > Convert To UTF 8.

Comment: Also note the significant change in file size after you 'save As' the existing .sql file with utf-8 encoding ! Almost half of the size compared to given file. In my case the mysqldump was taken using a Windows Power Shell, that program messed up the encoding.

Answer (score 5):

May be your dump.sql is having garbage character in beginning of your file or
there is a blank line in beginning.

Answer (score 4):

`zcat /path/to/file.sql.gz | mysql -u 'root' -p your_database`

Comment: Easiest solution

Answer (score 3):

Its must you file dump.sql problem.Use Sequel Pro check your file ecoding.It should be garbage characters in your dump.sql.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but found out that the dump file was actually a MSSQL Server backup, not MySQL.

Sometimes legacy backup files play tricks on us. Check your dump file.

On terminal window:

```
~$ cat mybackup.dmp
```

The result was:

```
TAPE??G?"5,^}???Microsoft SQL ServerSPAD^LSFMB8..... etc...
```

To stop processing the cat command:

```
CTRL + C
```

Answer (score 2):

Under linux
Ungzip your file using gunzip
Edit your unzip sql file using

> vi unzipsqlfile.sql

Remove the first binary line with esc dd
go to the bottom of the file with esc shift g
remove the last binary line with dd
save the file esc x:
Then reimport to mysql with :

> mysql -u username -p new_database < unzipsqlfile.sql

I performed that with a 20go sql file from a jetbackup cpanel mysql backup.
Be patient to wait vi doing the job for big files

Answer (score 1):

The file you are trying to import is a zip file. Unzip the file and then try to import again.

Answer (score 1):

I know the original posters question was solved, but I came here via Google, and the various answers eventually led me to discovering that my SQL was dumped with a different default charset than the one used to import it. I got the same error as the original question, but as our dump was piped into another MySQL client, we couldn't go the route of opening it with another tool and saving it differently.

For us, the solution turned out to be the `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` option, to be used both on the call of `mysqldump` as well as the call to import it via `mysql`. Of course, the value of the parameter may differ for others facing the same problem, it's just important to keep it the same, as the servers (or the tools) default setting might be any charset.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the entire string you wrote? As I am having the same situation as you. I am though still not sure why it's not working for me. it's on the same server, trying to make a staging of a website with the `mysqldump -uUSER -p user_db | gzip > user_db_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M").sql.gz` then trying to import it using `gunzip -c user_db_datetime.sql.gz | mysql -uUSER -p user_db`

Comment: Our string would not be helpful to you, as it is a huge collection of various custom settings. The way you describe your situation, my answer would not apply: my problem arose from the dumping computer/connection being a different setup than the restoring one, so we needed to specify the default charset in order to force them to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I exported all databases with mysqldump on a PowerShell:

`mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases`

When I tried to import it on a PowerShell:

`mysql -u root -p < .\all-databases.sql`

I got an error saying something with `<` being reserved for future versions.

So I tried the above command with `cmd` and got the same error like OP.

The solution was to use PowerShell and the following command:

`Get-Content '.\all-databases.sql' | &mysql.exe -u user -p`

Comment: Thanks to you I realized it's better not to mysqldump over powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Your File should be only .sql extension, (.zip, .gz .rar) etc will not support.
example: dump.sql

Answer (score 0):

Old but gold!

On MacOS (Catalina 10.15.7) it was a bit weird:
I had to rename my `dump.sql` into `dump.zip` and after that, i had to use finder(!) to unzip it.
in terminal, `unzip dump.zip` oder `tar xfz dump.sql[or .gz .tar ...]` leads to error msgs.

Finally, finder has unziped it totally fine, after that i could import the file without problems.

Answer (score 0):

File should be dump.sql. It could happen because you didn't extract file. If it's dump.sql.gz for example then extract file from archive.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 and I tried to import a mysql database. my colleague sent me the file in db.sql.gz format. I unzipped it and tried to import it but was getting this error. Ghasem Pahlavan's solution worked for me but for a beginner, I want to add something more. from the Linux terminal go to the directory where the file is at. for me it was in the downloads folder.

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/your_username/Downloads
```

after that run this command

```
tar xf db.sql.gz
```

Note: I had installed Ubuntu before.

Answer (score 0):

[@user1434997](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1434997/user1434997) I see none of the answers really solved [your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17158367/7496293), except for [@Torque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202894/torque)'s. At first, I assumed the issue to be binary data orientated because of the Error message solution, but it turns out this is an error related to the **method of your mysqldump**.

My error looked like this, very similar to yours:

```
ERROR at line 1365: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected.
```

In my research i eventually found this post https://gist.github.com/ntamvl/a81b90221f37e064ada9efdeb9b55c42 which described a **different mysql dump approach** also involving using **utf8 characterization** which I outline below, **this solved my problem** and i learnt something new:

Instead of:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p database > utf8.dump
```

...followed by:

```
mysql -u username -p database < dump_file
```

You should rather:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p database -r utf8.dump
```

...followed by a database login approach for the import:

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 database
mysql> SET names 'utf8'
mysql> SOURCE utf8.dump
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to fix error:

```sh
zcat {address_sql_database(.tar.gz)} | mysql -u root -p {database_name} --binary-mode
```

Comment: Why? Please explain how it anwers the question.