# mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I used this script for years on my VPS. And it's still working.

```
DBLIST=`mysql -uroot -pROOT_PASSWORD -ANe"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name) FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema')" | sed 's/,/ /g'`
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="-uroot -pROOT_PASSWORD --single-transaction --routines --triggers"
BACKUP_DEST="/home/backup/db/"
for DB in `echo "${DBLIST}"`
do
    mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB} | gzip > ${BACKUP_DEST}/${DB}.sql.gz &
done
wait
tar -czvf /home/backup/db2/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`_db.tar.gz ${BACKUP_DEST}
```

Now I'm moving to another hosting. I 'm trying to use the same script (of course I changed ROOT_PASSWORD with the new credentials) but I don't know why I get this:

```
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

Answer (score 46):

```
20:47:59 0 ~] $ perror 32
OS error code  32:  Broken pipe
```

So errno 32 is "broken pipe". You're piping the mysqldump output to `gzip` , so this means gzip terminated prior to mysqldump finished. Could e.g. be because your disk is full, or gzip surpassed any max CPU time/usage your host has in place.

Comment: Uhm.. disk is not full and CPU is free. :(

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno You are telling us you use a VPS, have you verified they don't have limits in place ? It's quite common for a VPS to limit your CPU usage, and kill processes that use too much CPU. Anyway, you now have an indication that gzip is getting killed, so you can play around with that, e.g. NOT pipe the output to gzip, but directly to a file and see how that goes.

Comment: @nos Resurrecting to note that indeed a CPU limit was my issue on AWS. I solved it by `nice`ing the dump.

Comment: If the disk is not full and CPU is free, try this: create a basic text file, and run the gzip command on it, you will soon realize what's wrong (the way I figured it out having the same error message)

Comment: This error in this scenario can definitely be a symptom of a full disk.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem due to a couple of typos.

1. I typed the name of the db user incorrectly. I had `"db_user_1"` when he was really `"db_user1"`.
2. After the pipe I forgot the `>` in `gzip > myfile.tar.gz`.

But I recommend you upgrade to MySQL 5.6+ asap, so you can stop exposing database passwords other users.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20854048/631764) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure the folder /home/backup/db/ (which your are using to store the backup) has write access permission (to quick check: try using chmod -R 777 on that folder and run the script to make sure).

Comment: +1 This was the problem in my case, folder must have 0777 CHMOD, in my case it had 0755, so it depends of mysql users right

Answer (score 3):

I was surprised I couldn't do a dump of my DB, I was able to do it the day before. Now, I was getting this error.

As *nos* said, the error message means Broken pipe, which means the output cannot be written to disk. In my case, **my SSH user had no permission to write in the folder I was targeting** in my mysqldump instruction.

You can output your dump in your `/home/your_user` directory to see it you still get the same error. Doing so solved my problem.

Comment: This is not true. Check @alexw answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was using `mysqldump` from the CLI and trying to pipe to gzip and/or a file and getting a "permission denied" error.

Even as `sudo`, I was getting an error because although I was running `mysqldump` as `sudo`, the pipe was still trying to use **the user account I was logged in to the shell as** to write the output.  In this case, my shell user account did not have permissions to write to the target directory.

To get around this, you can use the `tee` command in conjunction with `sudo`:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --routines --events --triggers --add-drop-table --extended-insert -u backup -h 127.0.0.1 -p --all-databases | gzip -9 | sudo tee /var/backups/sql/all_$(date +"%Y_week_%U").sql.gz > /dev/null
```

The `| sudo tee /var/backups/...` is what lets us pipe to a directory that is only writable by `root`.  The `> /dev/null` suppresses `tee` from dumping its output directly to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Faced with the same problem.
I do not know why exactly, but if you add the utility PV concluded that all works. Maybe it depends on your shell bash/sh.

```
sudo apt-get install pv
```

PipeViewer it a very usefull utility, it allows you to visualize processes of writing to disk, for example.

Script for example

```
mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB} | gzip | pv > ${BACKUP_DEST}/${DB}.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Its so old topic, but I'm facing that problem and find that:

My file  name: `db_26/03.tar.gz` its raising an error like above; but when I use: `db.tar.gz` there is no error.

So you should check your file name

Comment: I'm +1-ing this because it worked for us, but I'd really love it if someone could explain WHY this fixes it. For us, the old filename works if the command was run through cron, but not in command line.

Comment: You have a `/` forward slash in your filename, so it is trying to use `03.tar.gz` inside the (non existent) directory `db_26`

Answer (score 1):

Check if the folder exist in your location, /home/backup/db/

if no, create every subfolder.

Command: 
mkdir /home/backup/db/

then run your command again.

Comment: This was also the problem for us. I was running Deployer on a new environment and it was not allowed to create folders. When I created the folder manually it went fine in subsequent runs.

Answer (score 1):

Errno 32 is "broken pipe" so any error that is happening with the pipe destination (in this case gzip) will cause errno 32.  If the directory structure has changed and your `${BACKUP_DEST}` no longer refers to a directory that exists this problem would occur.

I would debug this by piping something else to your gzip command or creating an uncompressed backup not involving gzip.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error, when piping mysqldump output to s3cmd. It was caused by using the wrong version of s3cmd. On Ubuntu Trusty and Debian Wheezy the packaged version of s3cmd command doesn't support stdin (because they have version 1.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

What helped me with this problem is

```
export LANG=C
```

prior to running mysqldump per https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/771