# Errors: Incorrect database name 'databaseName AND mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, pipe

SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/sh

mysqldump --opt --protocol='TCP' -h'XXXXXXXX' -u 'XXXX' --password='XXXXX' databaseName | mysql -h 'XXXXX' -u'XXXXX' --password='XXXXX' databaseName
```

Before running script, `chomd 775` on script and execute it using `bash filename.sh`.
Get errors:

> 'ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'databaseName
> mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

Disk space and write permissions are not the cause. What else may I try?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you didn't specify the correct database name as the last argument.

Comment: Did you replace `databaseName` with the actual name of the database that you want to update?

Comment: Yes. I replaced the databaseName  with the actual name of the database that I want to update. And, I am certain of the DB name; I am sure the name I used is right.

Comment: error 32 seems to be a pipe error. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288271/mysqldump-got-errno-32-on-write

Comment: Error 32 in `mysqldump` is because of the error in `mysql`. It's trying to write to the pipe, but `mysql` exited because the database doesn't exist.

Comment: The error message should have `'` before and after the database name, but the second `'` is missing. Is that a copying error or is it really missing ?

Comment: If the latter, I suspect there's a `\r` character in your script. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: I actually did have the single quote around the database, like 'xxx'   The DB still was not recognized. I also saw before writing this post, the other ticket, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288271/mysqldump-got-errno-32-on-write. 
   More than likely there is an issue with the \r. I will try that.

Comment: continued....However, the other issue is the pipe.   Writing to the pipe creates deadlocks which takes down the system. So, I am going to try a two step approach and do the backup to file and then read the file into the other DB. Unless someone knows how to prevent the deadlock, I think I need to use the two part solution. Thank you to all for your comments/help.