# PHPMYADMIN error while importing big sql dump

Tags: mysql, dump

I am trying to import a big SQL dump into my mysql database but I got an error which the following.
Via PHPMYADMIN interface I didn't manage to import it, it says too voluminous.
So I tried with command line: `mysql -uroot -p dbsnp < SNP_HGVS.sql` but I got this error:
`ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query:`d�L'.`

Do you know how to resolve this issue?
Many thanks.

Comment: Is it okay to use `mysql -uroot -p` instead of `mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: Are you sure the dump is formatted correctly for MySQL (i.e. coming from another mysql source of similar settings)?
Are you sure your server you're importing the data to has similar settings to the source of the SQL dump?

Comment: @WaltSorensen, Hi Walt, actually, the dump wasn't correctly setup. I re-extract the archive and now it works.

Comment: Glad to hear you are up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per clarification question and comments:

The source SQL dump was not correctly setup and formatted for MySQL. Re-dumping the data with the correct MySQL configuration/format resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the character of dump file is not UTF-8.As per the error you need to --binary-mode on. Please check the link: [[Enable binary mode while restoring a Database from an SQL dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158367/enable-binary-mode-while-restoring-a-database-from-an-sql-dump][1])

Comment: I took a look at your link, when I add option `--binary -o` it displays:`ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\O'.` any idea?