# Error ASCII '\0' when importing 29GB .sql file into mysql 5.7 database on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, database, database-restore, mysqlimport

I have 29GB magento db .sql file that need to be imported into mysql database, I am using Ubuntu 22.04 operating system

I import into database using command line as below

`mysql -u root -p`

`mysql > USE magento_project1`
`mysql > source db_dump.sql`

The import seems to be working fine at first, but after a few hours of importing error as below comes out

`ERROR at line 44259: ASCII '\0' appeard in the statement, but this is not alllowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: '`

Attached the image of the error

[image: error ASCII]

I noticed the query stopped when at the part it need to insert data into sales_order_payment table

I have try

1. rename the db_dump.sql file to db_dump.sql.gz

- based on solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158367/enable-binary-mode-while-restoring-a-database-from-an-sql-dump)

2. import using command `mysql -u root -p -f -D database_name < db_dump.sql.gz`
3. when create database, create charset as utf8mb4, collation utf8mb4_general_ci
4. import using command `mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D database_name --binary-mode -o < db_dump.sql`

- based on solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383975/mysql-error-ascii-0-while-importing-sql-file-on-linux-server)

When i write command `file db_dump.sql.gz` I get the result as below

`db_dump.sql.gz: ASCII text, with very long lines (37268)`

My ubuntu is already `sudo apt-update` and `sudo apt-upgrade` with mysql, php, nginx and elasticsearch installed and enabled

But none of the solution above fix the issue I am having

Answer (score 0):

Able to fix the issue by dumping new database from magento cloud using command below

`magento-cloud db:dump`

0 -> Staging -> 0 ( database )

then import the db into local using command below

`mysql -u root -p -f -D local_db < dumped_db.sql`

Not sure what cause the error above on the first place, might be the db corrupted somewhere during transfer between pendrive ?