# How do I get rid of this character ï»¿?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

This character:

```
ï»¿
```

shows up on my site 3 times and for all 3 cases it's shown after a closed div tag.  I searched the web and SOF and there are some solutions but none of them worked on mine so decided to post here.  I am using .NET.  I realize that this is not sufficient info but i am new to programming so not sure what other info you might need.  Please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you include or import some files into your source files?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an byte order mark. Please check your source and output encoding.

Comment: Except that the OP says they appear in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the Byte Order Mark (BOM). It was driving me crazy too. I researched and started reading about BOM and tried adding charset="UTF-8" to some script tags but no go.

I use Dreamweaver and found that when I saved (save as) some recent html files, the option for "Include Unicode Signature (BOM) was checked. I unchecked and saved and it resolved the unwanted characters (I guess it saves it without the BOM)!!

Updating the meta tags charset to UTF-8 will resolve this too and is recommended (which means dozens of pages for me) but I needed this quick fix.

Also, saving with notepad++ looks to do the trick as well. Here's a related article wrt ++ and settings wrt BOM: [notepad++ converting ansi encoded file to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/notepad-converting-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8)

I hope this help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I use Dreamweaver and found that when I saved (save as) some recent html files, the option for "Include Unicode Signature (BOM) was checked. I unchecked and saved and it resolved the unwanted characters (I guess it saves it without the BOM)!!

This is the perfect solution. its worked for me.
thx everyone