# syntax error near unexpected token `fi' while checking no of arguments passed

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting and created a script to check arguments are passed or not using if else condition . But it is always giving a error **'syntax error near unexpected token `fi'** '

is it always required to use **';'** after if condition brackets.
I runned it online on http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php it is working well but not on my system(Centos 6.2). Am i missing something in env settings or is it something else.

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "print a message"
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Argument are passed to shell script"
else
    echo "No arguments are passed to shell script"
fi
```

**Error message**

```
[root@local shell_scripts]# sh test.sh 12 13
test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
test.sh: line 7: `fi'
[root@local shell_scripts]#
```

**my env details**

```
[root@local shell_scripts]# env
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.17 49656 22
PERL5LIB=/home/bharat/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi:/home/bharat/perl5/lib/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base /home/bharat/perl5
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/6
USER=bharat
PATH=/home/bharat/perl5/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/home/bharat/perl5/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/bharat/bin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/bharat
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
HOME=/root
SHLVL=4
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=/home/bharat/perl5
LOGNAME=bharat
CVS_RSH=ssh
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/bharat/perl5
_=/bin/env
[root@local shell_scripts]#
```

Comment: Try adding `;` before `fi` (am on windows now, so cannot test myself).

Comment: Can you show the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: Are you sure that you added `; then` in the `if` statement in your script?

Comment: Code can be indented with four spaces. It is not necessary to use HTML for this.

Comment: you may want to run this script with `bash`, not `sh`. Though it will unlikely solve your problem.

Comment: @Bharat Was your script created on Windows? If so, it probably contains DOS line endings, which can confuse the `bash` parser. Remove them with `dos2unix` or a similar tool.

Comment: @chepher yes i created my script on Window7 using notepad++
when i opened my script in vi editor on server i found that it was having character <feff> at the beginning of file. After removing it things went well. Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/notepad-converting-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8

Answer (score 3):

Answering the first of your questions: `;` is not required after `if` condition. Syntactically, `then` should go to a separate line. If `then` is in the 1st line, you use `;`. The following code is correct:

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    echo ok
fi
```

Also, these brackets are not actually `if` condition brackets. If condition is any valid bash command, and brackets are equivalent to `test`, see `man test` for ref.

The following are valid `if` statement beginnings:

```
if cp a.txt b.txt ; then ...
if test $# -eq 1 ; then ...
```

The second one is equivalent to your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
$ cat > f.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "print a message"
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Argument are passed to shell script"
else
    echo "No arguments are passed to shell script"
fi
$ bash f.sh 
print a message
No arguments are passed to shell script
```