# Arabic language text is not display proper in front side

Tags: php, opencart

I have using arabic language in OpenCart site. & also, I have add custom some text in arabic language. but, it text is not display proper in front side.

**Our module language file code.**

```
//  Website: WWW.OpenCartArab.com

//  E-Mail : info@OpenCartArab.com


// Heading 

$_['heading_title']  = 'ãäÊÌÇÊ ÇÎÑì';

$_['tab_latest']     = 'ÂÎÑ';

$_['tab_bestseller'] = 'ÇáÇßËÑ ãÈíÚÇ ';

$_['tab_featured']   = 'ããíÒ';

$_['tab_special']    = 'ÎÇÕ';


$_['text_reviews']   = 'Based on %s reviews.'; 

?>
```

but, Got front side this - ������ �����

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your php file is saved in utf-8 encoding (See here: [notepad++ converting ansi encoded file to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/notepad-converting-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8) OR here http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Notepad-Save-File-in-UTF-8.html) :)