# how to convert csv utf-8 multiple file?

Tags: python, csv

I have 300 CSV files

and this file encoded ANSI

so, I want to convert these files to utf-8

I think to use for loop can be achieved but I don't know how to do

how can I do this with python?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471087/convert-from-ansi-to-utf-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from ANSI to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471087/convert-from-ansi-to-utf-8)