# Encoding in Htmls

Tags: http, web, encoding

I have index.html that when I load it in the browser, all characters with special encoding (e.g. Hebrew, Arabic) are in Gibberish. 
But, when I load the same html in notepad++ , I get it in the right display.

The htmls meta tags are:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

EDIT:

Example for problematic characters:

אלו האותיות הבעיתיות

Any Advice?

Comment: Can you share some of the characters which show up wrong?

Comment: @Xeli yes, for example - ישראל

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the http server sets the correct http-header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. You can check the headers with

```
curl - I http://example.com
```

Comment: Rolled back attempt to reply.

Answer (score 0):

To problem will most likely be that the browser thinks it should use some encoding (UTF-8 in this case, because of the meta tag), while the bytes send to the browser are in a different encoding.

If it's a plain index.html file, so not generated by some application try to save the file with the correct encoding: utf-8.

you can use something like:

```
file index.html
```

To see what encoding might be used currently.

But to be sure re-save the file to utf-8 (see [notepad++ converting ansi encoded file to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/notepad-converting-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8) for tips how to do it)