# UnicodeDecodeError on python3

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, decoding

Im currently trying to use some simple regex on a very big .txt file (couple of million lines of text). The most simple code that causes the problem:

```
file = open("exampleFileName", "r")  
    for line in file:  
        pass
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 34, in <module>
    example()
  File "example.py", line 16, in example
    for line in file:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 7332: invalid continuation byte
```

How can i fix this? is utf-8 the wrong encoding? And if it is, how do i know which one is right?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte

Comment: Post the output of `file -bi [your_filename]`. You'll get an encoding. After that provide the `encoding` argument to `open()`.

Comment: what does file -bi command does?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like it is invalid UTF-8 and you should try to read with `latin-1` encoding. Try

```
file = open('exampleFileName', 'r', encoding='latin-1')
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the same when reading from command line?

I use `input()` function, is there a way to configure its encoding or is there some other configurable function?

Comment: How did you figure out to use latin-1 encoding?

Comment: 0xed is `í` characters which you can find in the latin-1 encoding

Comment: So confused! after unicode encoding came into the scene to cover all ~2 m code point, why latin-1 encoding is still here? shouldn't latin-1 encoding be a subset of UTF encoding? shouldn't all defined codes in latin-1 be now a part of UTF? if so, why UTF cannot support it?
(sorry I am kinda new in this field)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to identify the encoding on the fly. So, either user a method which I wrote as a comment or use similar constructions (as proposed by another answer), but this is a wild shot:

```py
try:
    file = open("exampleFileName", "r")
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    try:
        file = open("exampleFileName", "r", encoding="latin2")
    except: #...
```

And so on, until you test all the encodings from [Standard Python Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

So I think there's no need to bother with this nested hell, just do `file -bi [filename]` once, copy the encoding and forget about this.

**UPD.** Actually, I've found [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17249680/5164080) which you can use if you're on **Windows**.