# Can i insert emoji to php without lost unicode format?

Tags: php

Can I insert emoji to PHP without lost Unicode format?

I try to add this emoji  into PHP file but when I save the file it gives me an alert that "This file contain characters in Unicode format which will be lost if you save this file as an ANSI encode text file"

Comment: You need to change your file encoding to use UTF-8 (which can encode the emoji). Which editor and platform are you using?

Comment: Notepad++ and yes the PHP file is already with encoding utf-8 but when I add the emoji and saved and reopen the file it's changed to ANSI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [notepad++ converting ansi encoded file to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/notepad-converting-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8)

Comment: I check your link and yes my settings is like that, Also after reopening the file again I found that the emoji changed from  to ًںک‚

If you try you will find the issue.