# SonarQube shows Warn - Roslyn encoding is 'UTF-8' for C-Sharp

Tags: c#, jenkins, utf-8, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Our Sonar Build Environment details as follows:

```
• SonarQube Server Version - 5.6.6 (64-Bit). 
• Sonar-scanner- Version - 3.0.3.778.
• SonarQube Server Operating System – Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (64-Bit). 
• sonar-csharp-plugin-5.11.0.1761.jar
• Sonar Build Machine OS – Windows-7(64-bit)
```

**Problem Description:**

I am scanning **.cs** files through sonar-scanner. Whereas it finishes successfully, But it is not providing proper result over dashboard. Means it shows below warning message and also under C-sharp Project-->Code(Tab) Lines of code also shows zero.

```
WARN: Encoding detected by Roslyn and encoding used by SonarQube do not
match for file D:\Jenkins\workspace\project-scm \system\SCM-Model.cs. 
SonarQube encoding is 'windows-1252', Roslyn encoding is 'UTF-8'. File will be skipped.
```

Is there any way to resolve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue, open the file, save it without further changes to a the same file but now with UTF-8 encoding. One editor that let you do this is [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/how-do-i-convert-an-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8-with-notepad) SO question. Start the analysis again and your warnings should be gone.