# How to write both Chinese characters and English characters into a file (Python 3)?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, unicode, fwrite

I wrote a script to scrape the titles of a YouTube playlist page

Everything works fine, according to print statements, until I try to write the titles into a text file, at which point I get "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position..."

I've tried adding "encoding='utf8'" when I open the file, and while that fixes the error, all the Chinese characters are replaced by random, gibberish characters

I also tried encoding the output string with 'replace', then decoding it, but that also just replaces all the special characters with question marks

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib.request
import re

playlist_url = input("gib nem: ")

with urllib.request.urlopen(playlist_url) as response:
  playlist = response.read().decode('utf-8')
  soup = BS(playlist, "lxml")

title_attrs = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-title":re.compile(r".*")})
titles = [tag["data-title"] for tag in title_attrs]

titles_str = '\n'.join(titles)#.encode('cp1252','replace').decode('cp1252')

print(titles_str)
with open("playListNames.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(titles_str)
```

And here is the sample playlist I've been using to test:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3oW2tjiIxvSk0WKXaEiDY78KKbKghOOo

Comment: Are you sure that the gibberish is not due to your editor/whatever you use to display the results?

Comment: I just copied this code into a file and ran it without errors using the URL to gave. I'd show you some output but I'm having copy-and-paste issues, sorry. Are you running this code under Python 2, by any chance?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel I don't think so; I'm using Sublime Text 2

Comment: @holdenweb That's strange; I'm running the code under Python 3 with the Spyder IDE

Comment: You are appending to `playListNames.txt`. Are you sure the file's encoding is UTF? Did you try `creating a new file open("playListNames_new.txt", "w")` (and perhaps set encoding)?

Comment: @dm295 Oh, that worked!! Opening up the original file with Window's Notepad, it seems that the original encoding was ANSI. Would I be correct to assume that Windows writes files with ANSI encoding by default, and that Python's "encoding=" cannot change an existing file's encoding?

Comment: @HonestEscape: "*Would I be correct to assume that Windows writes files with ANSI encoding by default*" - no, there is no default encoding at the OS layer. NOTEPAD defaults to ANSI unless you specify otherwise. "*and that Python's "encoding=" cannot change an existing file's encoding?*" - correct, if you are not overwriting the file's existing content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is clear about file encoding:

> `encoding` is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the
>   file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is
>   platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns),
>   but any text encoding supported by Python can be used. See the codecs
>   module for the list of supported encodings.

To answer questions from your last comment.

1. You can find out what's the preferred encoding on Windows with

   ```
   import locale
   locale.getpreferredencoding()
   ```

If `playListNames.txt` was created with `open('playListNames.txt', 'w')` then the value returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()` was used for encoding.

If the file was created manually then the encoding depends on the editor's default/preferred encoding.

2. Refer to [How to convert a file to utf-8 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191359/how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf-8-in-python) or [How do I convert an ANSI encoded file to UTF-8 with Notepad++? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/how-do-i-convert-an-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8-with-notepad).

Answer (score 1):

Using an encoding will fix your problem.  Windows defaults to an ANSI encoding that on US Windows is Windows-1252.  It doesn't support Chinese.  You should use `utf8` or `utf-8-sig` as the encoding.  Some Windows editors prefer the latter and assume ANSI otherwise.

```
with open('playListNames.txt','w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
```

Comment: To be more accurate, *Windows* doesn't care about file encodings at all, it is *Text Editors*, like Notepad, that do.